# No Network Connection in WinXP image from Microsoft running on VirtualBox 3.1.6 OSE (Ubuntu 10.04) due to missing CD Rom

Tags: windows-xp, networking, drivers, ubuntu-10.04, virtualbox

I'd like to test local websites in IE7 and IE8.To do that I thought about using the free Microsoft images: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/setup/default.mspx
I converted the VHDs to VDIs to make them run in VirtualBox. ( http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=721 ) This works fine. The problem is that in this Windows XP installation there is no Network Adapter configured. Actually nothing at all is configured because it needs the Windows XP CD Rom to do that. If I would have a Windows XP CD Rom, I would not need to run the Microsoft image, so is there some kind of workaround to get an internet connection? Meanwhile I set "bridged" in VirtualBox. But this doesn't help because "ipconfig /all" in the guest system doesn't show any data because nothing is configured. How can I get a connection to my local Apache (Host system). http://localhost would be enough. 
By the way: I can't install the "Guest additions". When I do that, the 3 days trial period of the guest system is suddenly gone, so I can't use it anymore and it is senseless. 
Any ideas?

**Update:** I've tried the Vista image and it gets an internet connection. From Vista image I can get to my site with 192.168.1.3/mywebsite in the browser url. So actually I don't care about the WinXP issue anymore but I would be glad if anyone still knows a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem indirectly solved:

I've tried the **Vista** image and it gets an internet connection. From Vista image I can get to my site with 192.168.1.3/mywebsite in the browser url.

So actually I don't care about the WinXP issue anymore but I would be glad if anyone still knows a solution.